# Flutter IDE Shortcuts

Tags: flutter, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am new to Flutter and I am learning it bit by bit. I am not getting shortcuts in Flutter. I know I have to enable it somewhere and I do not know where. Meanwhile, I am using Android Studio editor IDE.
[Flutter Shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkdCM.jpg). I am not getting that which is in the image.

Thanks for your kind help.
Regards,
Kannan

Answer (score 0):

In android studio, you can do this by taking your cursor on the widget you want to modify and the type `Alt + Enter` on Windows and `Option(alt) + Enter` on Mac. This will popup the context menu as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkdCM.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

In android studio ,if you want to find method definition in code or if you want to navigate to some class use this shortcut move your cursor on class and press `ctrl` button.

next one is you want to see parameters of widgets then move your cursor inside that widget and press `ctrl+space` .this will popup menu as shown  [image: here].